# Multiple Corrupted Instagram Images from multiple users from API

Tags: image, amazon-s3, instagram, corruption

We have encountered multiple corrupted Instagram Standard Images (612px).
This happens the last 3-4 days. And across multiple Instagram users.

Strangely this issue is only evident when the images are opened using Adobe Photoshop.
When viewed using Mac's finder or Preview this image corrupt problem is not visible.

It affects about 50% of our customers. And mostly about 10-20% of their choosen images. And some can affect around 50-100% of their images.

Example of corrupted images:
http://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/5875aa2eb24411e3bfe2124c49cf34ce_8.jpg
http://distilleryimage0.s3.amazonaws.com/3b3452a8b24411e3b352126f9f588c64_8.jpg

Again, this issue is only evident when the photos are being prepared to print.
Or when it is opened using Adobe Photoshop/Acrobat/Illustrator/Indesign.

Please help.

Thanks

Jeff

Comment: interesting, I noticed something different when viewing instagram photos on gramfeed from last few days, the images render with black/white blocky image initially and then actual image shows up, it does happen to about >50% of instagram photos.

Comment: It looks like, as of the most recent IG app update, photos taken via the app are encoded using JPEG's progressive DCT compression instead of the baseline DCT.

@krisrak That would explain the "blocky image then full image" view, as that is one of the effects of progressive DCTs in Jpeg

Comment: But if the jpeg is fully loaded, then there shouldn't be any problem with progressive compression isn't it? Is Amazon AWS somehow not compatible with decoding/storing the progressive compression? Any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Progressive DCT makes sense, I only see the blocky image first time it is loaded, after that it just loads immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve my issue with the same description. What I first did was download the images to my webserver exactly to what is was online, so I didn't change anything of the file contents, just get en then put in the file.

How I solved  my problem? I use PHP to generate the image now after I donwloaded it the same way. This is the simplified version of my script:

```
<?php
// Create an image instance
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('instagram_image.jpeg');

// Disable interlacing
imageinterlace($im, false); // did not use this but will do the same

// Save the image
imagejpeg($im, 'instagram_image.jpeg');
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

When I started using this simple create and save script it all worked again. It looks like it does nothing but it did a lot for me! Hope it helps someone saving a lot of time, took me 1,5 day to figure out the exact problem.

Comment: Thanks mate, we will try to implement this.